# Debian stretch: upgrade of `snmpd` giving an error

Tags: debian, sysvinit, snmp

During the latest security upgrades,  `snmpd` was upgraded to 5.7.3.

Before finishing the procedure, `apt-get upgrade` starting giving the error:

```
Starting SNMP services::Bad user id: snmp
```

`snmpd` is also not running. What is happening?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at the post-inst scripts of `snmpd`, it seems the default Debian user and group of the `snmpd` package, changed from `snmp` to `Debian-snmp`.

To correct it it was necessary to edit `/etc/default/snmpd` and change the following line from:

```
SNMPDOPTS='-Lf /dev/null -u snmp -g snmp -I -smux -p /var/run/snmpd.pid'
```

to:

```
SNMPDOPTS='-Lf /dev/null -u Debian-snmp -g Debian-snmp -I -smux -p /var/run/snmpd.pid'
```

After the change, the `apt-get upgrade` finished successfully and the `snmpd` service went up.

Relevant files:

`/var/lib/dpkg/info/snmpd.postinst` in Stretch:

```
SNMP_USER="Debian-snmp"
```

`/var/lib/dpkg/info/snmpd.postinst` in Jessie:

```
adduser --quiet --system --group --home $SNMPDIR \
                 --shell /usr/sbin/nologin snmp
```

Comment: This happened last April, not yesterday (the change was made in [March](https://packages.qa.debian.org/n/net-snmp/news/20160329T215952Z.html) and migrated to Stretch in April). Note also that the `/etc/default` file is only used with `sysvinit`, not systemd. I'm surprised `dpkg` didn't ask you what to do with the `/etc/default` file... If it didn't, I'd say it's worth filing a serious bug, since this will break upgrades from Jessie.

Comment: It just affected me yesterday... maybe a change in the postint scripts? it could have asked, I have to answer no, as I have custom lines there. Will have to test it out. I added the `sysvinit` tag,  and took you the yesterday remark, thanks.

Comment: Right, my comment was poorly phrased — I meant "this was changed last April". It would be great if you could file a bug though!

Comment: @StephenKitt I will try later to understand better what happened and will file that bug.